# Am a newbie in django, am trying to count number of app registration request but result does not display on the template?

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css

below is my code that i was trying to implement the task
my views.py
this is my view for counting the request
def appSummary_view(request):

```
   context = {}

   user = request.user
   applications = ApplicationRequest.objects.all().filter(developer=user)

   total_request = applications.count()
   registered_app = applications.filter(status=1).count()
   pending_app = applications.filter(status=0).count()

   context = {'total_request':total_request, 
  'registered_app':registered_app, 'pending_app':pending_app}
  print(applications)
  return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

#my models
this is my model for app request

```
class ApplicationRequest(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    developer = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s",
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)

    name_of_app = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True)

    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,null=True)

    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    redirect_uris = models.TextField(
    blank=True,
    help_text= ("Allowed URIs list, space separated")
)


   claim_of_property = models.TextField(
    blank=False,
    help_text= ("Proof of property, space separated"),null=True
)

   date_requested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



   status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name_of_app
```

#my forms.py
this is my form for registering the applications

```
class RegisterAppForm(forms.ModelForm):

  name_of_app = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Required.Please enter the           name of your applications')

  domain = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Required.Please enter the domain for your application')

  org_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Required.Please enter the name of the organization of your application')
  redirect_uris = forms.CharField(max_length=400,help_text='Required.Please enter redirect uris for your app')
  claim_of_property = forms.CharField(max_length=400, help_text='Required.Please provide the proof of property')


class Meta:
    model = ApplicationRequest
    fields = ('name_of_app', 'domain', 'org_name', 'redirect_uris' , 'claim_of_property')
```

template code this is my template code to show the request count

```
 <div>
        <div class="grid grid-rows-2 grid-flow-col gap-4">
        <div class="flex items-stretch space-x-4">
          <div class="row-span-full md:col-span-3 flex items-center justify-around p-6 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-lg" style="width: 26rem;">
            <div class="col-md">
              <div class="card text-center text-black  mb-3" id="total-applications">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Total App requests</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-4xl">{{total_request}}</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div>
          <div class="row-span-2 md:col-span-3 flex items-center justify-around p-6 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-lg "style="width: 26rem;">
            <div class="col-md">
              <div class="card text-center text-black  mb-3" id="registered-applications">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Registered Applications</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-4xl">{{registered_app}}</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <div class="row-span-2 md:col-span-3 flex items-center justify-around p-6 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-lg" style="width: 26rem;">
            <div class="col-md">
              <div class="card text-center text-black  mb-3" id="pending-applications">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-title ">Pending Applications</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-4xl">{{pending_app}}</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you try to print the context before calling the render function to make sure values are correct? If that is correct, the problem must be in the HTML. The `div` container surrounding the Registered applications row looks suspicious (the one with no classes), why is it there?

Comment: @vinkomlacic i tried printing the context but i get nothing

Comment: also i am asking the user=request.user is it correct because i was trying to count application registration request for a particular user . also thanks for your first comment @vinkomlacic

Comment: I also removed the div tag still there is no any results @vinkomlacic

Comment: Well, all seems correct to me. Are you sure the application requests are stored with the `developer` field correctly? If the context does not contain the data, that means the issue is in the view somewhere or the data might not be good in the database. So, not in the HTML. Can you provide the code where you create `ApplicationRequests`? Fetching user through `request.user` is pretty standard so it should work.

Comment: Yes, i checked the developer field and the application request corresponds to the developer but still the context is not rendered @vinkomlacic

Comment: Can you add to the question what do you get when you do `print(context)` after the line `context = {...}`? It cannot be nothing

Comment: i solved the problem , i forgot to include the path to the view ,that's is why everything was correct but no results were displayed, also thanks @vinkomlacic for all the help

Comment: In the future, post all of your code with the question. If you posted urls.py someone would have seen the error instantly. Even if it seems irrelevant to you. Usually that's where the problem is

Comment: Noted @vinkomlacic